# Pop-up message showing " Did you attach the CPU-Profile?" while trying to run live server in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have Live-Server extension installed in my VSCode.
I was trying to run the live-server but a pop-up appeared as below:

```
This is a reminder to make sure that you have not forgotten to attach 'c\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ritwickdey.LiveServer-unresponsive.cpuprofile.txt' to an existing performance issue.
```

I couldn't find much recourses to understand what the issue was or what action I should take about it.

BTW: Live Server is not loading the browser-page by its own, but at port:5500 its running.
Please Help.

Answer (score -1):

after researching i found this blog, where i got to know that its because of performance issue
https://www.nicoespeon.com/en/2019/11/fix-vscode-extension-performance-issue/

first thing bundle your vsCode extensions:https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/bundling-extension

if that solves the issue then great if not then add this extension to vsCode
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nicoespeon.abracadabra

hope the first link will provide complete solution.
Happy Learning